# np where produces "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Tags: python, numpy

I have read two bands from a remote sensed image and I want to subtract them. If the difference is greater than a threshold, I want the output to be 1, otherwise 0. Yet, this error keeps popping up **The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()**.
Below the lines of code are illustrated.

```
red_array = red.ReadAsArray()
swir1_array = swir1.ReadAsArray()
# Substracting the bands creating a raster that enhances ships ready for classification
# red_swir = np.where(((red_array > 2000) & (swir1_array > 900)), 0, red_array - swir1_array).astype(np.int16)
difference = (red_array - swir1_array).astype(np.int16)
red_swir = np.where((difference > 2000, 1, 0))
```

Any help here?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592. Even the easiest, most obvious possible searches for this question would directly point you at existing answers, because this question is asked constantly.

Comment: Show traceback.  I'd also test `difference > 2000` by itself.  I don't the `where` itself is raising the error.